# Read apache HttpClient response twice

Tags: spring-boot, httpclient, inputstream, aop

We are using apache HTTPClient to send request to third parties.
I have used AOP on execute() method to log request and response.

While logging response using aop I am writing below code

AOP CLASS CODE:

```java
private void logResponse(Object response, Logger logger, Long startTime) throws ParseException, IOException {
        if(response instanceof HttpResponse) {
            HttpResponse httpResponse = (HttpResponse) response;
            if(httpResponse.getEntity() != null) {
                String log = EntityUtils.toString(
                    httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()  // <== PROBLEMATIC LINE
                );
                logger.info(log);
            }
        }
    }
```

and in my third party caller class I am reading it again as I have to map json string response to corresponding response class.

```java
class Connector{
 public <T> postRequest(Class<T> responseClassOfType) {
      HttpResponse response = clientWrapper.sendRequest(httpClient, request);
      String result = EntityUtils.toString(
          response.getEntity()  // ==> faulty code. reading stream second time.
      );
      return mapper.getObjectFromJson(result, responseClassOfType);
 }
}
```

```java
class ClientWrapper {
public HttpResponse sendRequest(HttpClient httpClient, HttpRequestBase request) throws IOException {
        return httpClient.execute(request);
    }
}
```

There are many posts available to read input stream twice but I haven;t found any relevant ans fitting in my case.

Is my way of request response logging correct?
Or is there any other better way I can log request and response using httpClient.

Kindly help.

PS : 1. We dont want `<logger level="DEBUG" name="org.apache.http.wire" />` in our logback xml file as logs generated were not showing properly in kibana.

2. I cannot change Connector class methods.

Comment: *There are many posts available to read input stream twice but I haven;t found any relevant ans fitting in my case.* Why don't these work for you?

Comment: @Alan Hay They all suggested to convert input stream to byte array and recreate the inputstream using this cached byte array. As I have mentioned I cannot change connector class code so how does this help me ?

Comment: You don't show your aspect's pointcut, but how about intercepting `HttpResponse.getEntity()` or `HttpEntity.getContent()` instead of what you are intercepting now, then just logging the entity when it is read anyway? That way you would avoid to read the entity's input stream twice. Or intercept the stream content before it is converted to Json via `mapper.getObjectFromJson(..)`.

Comment: @GAURAVPANT Were you able to log the request and response body. Please let me know i am stuck with the same usecase.